# cordova build android for latest sdk errors

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

i have deleted node_module and plugins and tried npm install and ionic cordova build android --verbose to build apk or aab file to update on play store and  still getting errors also tried multiple solution like upgrading and downgrading versions of angular cordova java sdk and android studio plugins , npm version , nvm version upgrading. and downgrading.

```
Cannot read property 'find' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null
at D:\NEW\node_modules\cordova-android\lib\prepare.js:392:49
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at updateProjectSplashScreen (D:\NEW\node_modules\cordova-android\lib\prepare.js:388:7)
at updateProjectAccordingTo (D:\NEW\node_modules\cordova-android\lib\prepare.js:271:5)
at D:\NEW\node_modules\cordova-android\lib\prepare.js:69:21
at async Promise.all (index 0)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova.cmd build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +1ms
ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 7504: Error: Command failed:         taskkill /pid 7504 /T /F
ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "7504" not found.
ionic:utils-process
```

js:1048:16)
ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit    (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {

```
 ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 7504 /T /F
 ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "7504" not found.
ionic:utils-process
ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit   (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 14872: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 14872 /T /F
   ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "14872" not found.
ionic:utils-process
(internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
taskkill /pid 14872 /T /F
ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "14872" not found.
i(internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
 ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
 ionic:utils-process } +1ms
 ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +2ms`
```

```
[![info ionic][1]][1]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/UATrs.png][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UATrs.png
```

Comment: Show your ionic info, sounds like your cordova-android plugin maybe be out of date or you have installed a higher version than needed.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UATrs.png